# How can I call function every 30 seconds on every devices in the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am gonna try to explain my problem properly. I want to generate number every 30 seconds, like this :

```
function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
setTimeout(function(){
        getRandomNumber(0,14);
    }, 30000);
```

This works good, but not same on each device, like if I open the page with this code, I will get random number, but if my friend opens it after e.g. 5 seconds since I have opened the page, there arises delay. Is there any way to fix it? I thought something like getting time server and doing it according to him could work, but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: websockets, long-polling or any other omnidirectional server-client communication tech usually fit the bill in such cases - bearing in mind you have a server setup

Comment: This is a very difficult problem to solve. Assuming that time is in set correctly, and in sync, on all clients is a massive assumption and one most likely doomed to end badly. I would suggest reversing the procedure and pushing out a notification from the server to all clients, that way the only possible difference would be down to network latency. To do this, look in to using websockets.

Comment: You could set the first timeout so that it happens at the next even 30 seconds according to the system clock. If the sync has to be as exact as possible you should get the time from the server. The server could for example pass the milliseconds to next even 30 seconds by printing it as json and placing it to a js variable in the html or as an html data-attribute. Syncing via websockets probably would be most accurate, but with an initial timestamp you could get a fairly accurate result easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no perfect solution to this problem, here two options:

A simple one and a complicated one wich should be more precise.

---

**If you have the same time on all devices*** you could use `new Date().getTime() % 30000` for the first call, so they are all on sync, and then always use constant 30000 in the timeout.

```
function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
setTimeout(function() {
  getRandomNumber(0, 14);
}, new Date().getTime() % 30000); // first time use this
```

* Timezones won't matter, but the seconds of a minute

---

Another way would to let the server pass his time, and then guess the latency to correct the loading time, and use that instad of `new Date().getTime()`

Comment: Thanks, i will try it!

Comment: That is one **massive** assumption though, and even then the accuracy of JS timers isn't very reliable.

Comment: @CodeiSir, it was just to stress it ;)

Comment: Indeed, the only other way would to let the server pass a time, and then guess the latency to correct it and then use that time

Comment: @NinaScholz yes, thank you - I stressed it in the answer

Comment: How about using WebSocket instead and make the server "commands" to execute the function?

Comment: WebSockets has latency as well and it's another big thing to code. But indeed it would be a little better.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most simple solution would be to create a new `Date` object, read the seconds with `getSeconds`, then round it at a multiple of 30 and schedule the generator to the next step with `setTimeout`. Once it starts, you can decide either to schedule it again with the same function or to set an interval with `setInterval`.

If you don't want to rely on the local clock, I guess you have to use a service like *ntp*, but it requires you know what's the delta to apply to the time and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with one line of PHP.

This works here.

```
<script>
    function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }

    // The variable 'startTime' is synchronized with the server
    var startTime=parseInt(<?php echo date("now")?>);

    setInterval(function() {
        startTime++;
        if(startTime%30==0) document.write(parseInt(getRandomNumber(0, 14)).toString()+"<br>");
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

Note that I used setInterval instead of setTimeout, so it will repeat.